# Does the reputation you get from meta transfer to normal ask ubuntu?

Tags: support, reputation

I just got the privilege to participate in meta, but if I get reputation points here, will that be added to my normal Ask Ubuntu reputation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're asking doesn't actually exist.

The way Rep flows is Main Site -> Meta.  You gain rep on the main site and your rep goes up here (eventually) to match.  If you lose rep, that reflects here too.

Voting here does nothing to reputation - it's used solely to show agreement/disagreement with the post or support/nonsupport for a given answer or post.

So basically, we reward you for contributing on the main site with the rep system.  We don't reward you with rep for contributing on Meta.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't gain nor lose any rep in Meta and your rep on the main site is unaffected.

Comment: But why are there votes?

Comment: @UbuntuUser See the dupe target for the details.